# How to use ConsenSys/Tokens to create new token

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ico

As per [ConsenSys/Tokens](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens) copy/paste is highly discouraged. So what modification is required in Step:2 of this article [to create an EIP20](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@maxnachamkin/how-to-create-your-own-ethereum-token-in-an-hour-erc20-verified)
compatible token?

Should I just clone/download the repo and create new contract with my token name ( or even simply rename EIP20 to my token name) and use it as my new token?

I'm wondering, is there a recommended way to use [ConsenSys/Tokens] implementation?